# XAMPP Control Panel Apache and MySQL not working

Tags: xampp

```
Attempting to start Apache app...
Problem detected!
Port 80 in use by "Unable to get info" with PID 7596!
Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
You will need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
Problem detected
Port 443 in use by "Unable to get info" with PID 7596!
Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
You will need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port

Attempting to start MySQL app...
```

No error message for MySQL :(

Comment: What're you trying to do?

Comment: just start up my apache and sql and get it running but error - xampp control panel

Comment: Does anyone know the answer to this?

Comment: Post your command used to start and your config file, please.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: How're you starting `xampp`?

Comment: i click on "start" beside sql/apache and error pops up ( xampp control panel )